# PCA in R using the caret package vs prcomp PCA

Tags: r, pca, r-caret

I have a dataframe `data` with more than 50 variables and I am trying to do a PCA in R using the `caret` package.

```
library(caret)
library(e1071)
trans <- preProcess(data,method=c("YeoJohnson", "center","scale", "pca"))
```

If I understand this code correctly, it applies a YeoJohnson transformation (because `data` has zeros in it), standardises `data` and than applies PCA (by default, the function keeps only the PCs that are necessary to explain at least 95% of the variability in the data)

However, when I use the `prcomp` command,

```
  model<-prcomp(data,scale=TRUE)
```

I can get more outputs like printing the `summary` or doing `plot(data, type = "l")` which I am not able to do in `trans`. Does anyone know if there are any functions in `caret` package producing the same outputs as in `prcomp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the principal components themselves with the `predict` function.

```
df <- predict(trans, data)
summary(df)
```

You won't have exactly the same output as with `prcomp`: while `caret` uses `prcomp()`, it discards the original `prcomp` class object and does not return it.